# Duplicated driver

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I am checking on faulty driver in my computer and I found there are 2 driver with the same name. I am wondering is this normal.

I am using windows xp and a laptop of lenovo 3000 c200.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's normal to see two display adapters listed under system devices. It's how most Windows XP display drivers handle multiple outputs.